# How do I recycle an IIS AppPool with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, iis-6

I haven't really done any Windows scripting at all, so I am at a loss on how to pull this one off.  Anyway, basically what we want to do is have a script that will take an argument on which IIS AppPool to recycle.  I have done some research on Google and haven't had much success on getting things to work.

Here is what I am trying now:

```
$appPoolName = $args[0]
$appPool = get-wmiobject -namespace "root\MicrosoftIISv2" -class "IIsApplicationPools" Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "W3SVC/APPPOOLS/$appPoolName"}
$appPool.Recycle()
```

and the error I get:

```
Get-WmiObject : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name '$_.Name -eq "W3SVC/APPPOOLS/$appPoolName"'.
```

Anyway, it would be nice if I also knew how to debug things like this.  I already fixed one bug with the original script by doing gwmi -namespace "root\MicrosoftIISv2" -list.  Any other tips like that one would be great.

Thanks!

**Update**:  Here is some more info

```
$appPool = gwmi -namespace "root\MicrosoftIISv2" -class "IISApplicationPools" | Get-Member

.   TypeName: System.Management.ManagementObject#root\MicrosoftIISv2\IIsApplicationPools

Name                MemberType   Definition
----                ----------   ----------
Caption             Property     System.String Caption {get;set;}
Description         Property     System.String Description {get;set;}
InstallDate         Property     System.String InstallDate {get;set;}
Name                Property     System.String Name {get;set;}
Status              Property     System.String Status {get;set;}
__CLASS             Property     System.String __CLASS {get;set;}
__DERIVATION        Property     System.String[] __DERIVATION {get;set;}
__DYNASTY           Property     System.String __DYNASTY {get;set;}
__GENUS             Property     System.Int32 __GENUS {get;set;}
__NAMESPACE         Property     System.String __NAMESPACE {get;set;}
__PATH              Property     System.String __PATH {get;set;}
__PROPERTY_COUNT    Property     System.Int32 __PROPERTY_COUNT {get;set;}
__RELPATH           Property     System.String __RELPATH {get;set;}
__SERVER            Property     System.String __SERVER {get;set;}
__SUPERCLASS        Property     System.String __SUPERCLASS {get;set;}
ConvertFromDateTime ScriptMethod System.Object ConvertFromDateTime();
ConvertToDateTime   ScriptMethod System.Object ConvertToDateTime();
Delete              ScriptMethod System.Object Delete();
GetType             ScriptMethod System.Object GetType();
Put                 ScriptMethod System.Object Put();


gwmi -namespace "root\MicrosoftIISv2" -class "IISApplicationPools"


__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : IIsApplicationPools
__SUPERCLASS     : CIM_LogicalElement
__DYNASTY        : CIM_ManagedSystemElement
__RELPATH        : IIsApplicationPools.Name="W3SVC/AppPools"
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 5
__DERIVATION     : {CIM_LogicalElement, CIM_ManagedSystemElement}
__SERVER         : IRON
__NAMESPACE      : root\MicrosoftIISv2
__PATH           : \\IRON\root\MicrosoftIISv2:IIsApplicationPools.Name="W3SVC/A
                   ppPools"
Caption          :
Description      :
InstallDate      :
Name             : W3SVC/AppPools
Status           :
```

Comment: Just a quick style note.. rather than using $args to get the app pool name, you could declare a named paramater.  PowerShell scripts will take named parameters and fill them first by name and then by position.  You can also specify a type for the parameter.
Example:
(param [string]$AppPoolName)

Comment: Curious if you got this going with the updated WMI class name suggestion made in my answer?

Answer (score 18):

**Where-Object** is a filter that expects something as in input. There seems to be a missing **pipe**, before the *where filter*.

Try:

```
$appPoolName = $args[0]
$appPool = get-wmiobject -namespace "root\MicrosoftIISv2" -class "IIsApplicationPool" | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "W3SVC/APPPOOLS/$appPoolName"}
$appPool.Recycle()
```

**Edit**: I noticed that the WMI class was *IISApplicationPools*, which as you saw, did not show us the Recycle method when piped to **Get-Member**. This needs to be changed to *IISApplicationPool* (non-plural). With that change, you are able to use the Recycle method. The code above has been updated.

Comment: It's telling me I have a null-values expression.  Any idea how I can find out the properties of the object?

Comment: Yes. Try and pipe the results of your Get-WmiObject to Get-Member. This will show you the properties/methods on the incoming object.

Comment: Also, try taking out the Where-Object part to see the full list of results returned.

Answer (score 7):

Using the data from this question I was able to create 2 very useful functions.

- Get-IisAppPools
- Recycle-IisAppPool

The code:

```
function Get-IisAppPools {

    Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\MicrosoftIISv2" -Class "IIsApplicationPool" -Filter 'name like "W3SVC/APPPOOLS/%"' 
         | ForEach-Object { $_.Name.ToString().SubString(15) } 

}

function Recycle-IisAppPool([string]$appPoolName) { 

     Invoke-WmiMethod -Name Recycle -Namespace "root\MicrosoftIISv2" -Path "IIsApplicationPool.Name='W3SVC/APPPOOLS/$appPoolName'" 

}
```

You can use these functions like this

```
Recycle-IisAppPool DefaultAppPool
Get-IisAppPools | ? { $_ -match "v4.0$" } | % { Recycle-IisAppPool $_ }
```

Comment: I am very happy to find out some code I wrote is helping others. Thanks for the comment. It made my day.

Answer (score 4):

When using get-WMIObject you should probably use -filter instead of piping to Where-Object.  the filter parameter uses WQL syntax language instead of PowerShell's, so don't let that trip you up.

```
$appPoolName = $args[0]
$appPool = get-wmiobject -namespace "root\MicrosoftIISv2" -class "IIsApplicationPools" -filter 'name="W3SVC/APPPOOLS/$appPoolName"'
```

Having said that putting the pipe there should work, and certainly makes it easier to work with unless you already know WQL.

Answer (score 4):

In Powershell:

```
$pool = Get-IISAppPool -Name <name>

$pool.recycle()
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a Powershell-specific answer, but iisapp.vbs will list the running application pools, and there is a /r flag to recycle a specific app pool.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a WQL query to get just the AppPool you want; this has the advantage of filtering the results on the WMI side, which is especially handy when getting objects from a remote machine.

```
(Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM IIsApplicationPool WHERE Name = 'W3SVC/AppPools/$appPoolName'" -Namespace 'root\MicrosoftIISv2').Recycle()
```

Answer (score 0):

With IIS 8.0 I've found I had to use `-namespace root\webadministration -class ApplicationPool`

For example, to recycle an Application Pool in IIS 8 remotely using PowerShell:

As always, please test this first by listing the application pools.  Just remove the `| where` and the first `(` from the command:

```
gwmi -comp WebServer01 -namespace root\webadministration -class ApplicationPool

#Recycle app pool by name.
(gwmi -comp WebServer01 -namespace root\webadministration -class ApplicationPool | `
where {$_.Name -eq 'YourAppPool'}).recycle()
```

And on one line:

```
(gwmi -comp WebSserver01 -namespace root\webadministration -class ApplicationPool | where {$_.Name -eq 'YourAppPool'}).recycle()
```

Answer (score 0):

For PS 3.0+, you can use CIM, which should be faster than WMI.

```
Invoke-CimMethod -Query 'SELECT * FROM ApplicationPool WHERE Name = "$appPoolName"' -Namespace root\WebAdministration -MethodName Recycle
```