# Restarting an app pool using powershell Exception

Tags: powershell

I am trying to restart an application pool remotely using powershell.

```
net use $ToPath $pass /USER:$usr
$appPool = get-wmiobject -computername $ToServerName -namespace "root\MicrosoftIISv2" -class "IIsApplicationPool" | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "W3SVC/APPPOOLS/$appPoolName"} -Authentication PacketPrivacy
#(Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM IIsApplicationPool WHERE Name = 'W3SVC/AppPools/$appPoolName'" -Namespace 'root\MicrosoftIISv2').Recycle()
$appPool.Recycle()
net use $ToPath /delete
```

I basically use the same command that I use to move files remotely, where I set up a net user.  I get a Get-WMI exception

Comment: Can you not use actual remote PowerShell? Otherwise check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198623/how-do-i-recycle-an-iis-apppool-with-powershell?rq=1

Comment: You should add your exception to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to make sure that this question was answered for those that come after me.  It turns out that I was piping the `-Authentication PacketPrivacy` parameter to the wrong command